# Selecting TWO elements with jQuery, Highlighting selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a list of items in a `<div>` tag and when users *hover* over my element, it highlights.

Now I'm trying to figure out how to allow users to select **two** elements to click. When user clicks the element, it should be highlighted.

After selecting two items, users shouldn't be able to select anymore, **unless** they unselect one of the selected items (to make the highlight disappear) and then select something else.

Is this possible?

My current hovers:

```
                // hovers over element
                $('.media-search').hover(function(){
                    var $this = $(this);
                    // highlighting the object
                    $this.toggleClass('selectMedia');

                    $this.find('.next-btn').show();

                },function(){
                    var $this = $(this);

                    // removing the object
                    $this.removeClass('selectMedia');
                    $this.find('.next-btn').hide();
                });
```

`.selectMedia` is just the css that highlights my `.media-search` div.

Thanks!

Comment: `when users click on a div element,` click ?? or u meant hover ??? since i cannot find click event in  your posted code...or u missed it??

Comment: I can't see your code doing any of what you stated it does. There's no `click` handler whatsoever

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: @bipen I'm so sorry for confusion, its really late, and I thought I had a click on it. But its hover. I'm trying to get click though and reworded my question

Comment: @Alexander please see my updated post, Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question it looks like you are trying to achieve something like this:

```
$('.media-search').hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
}).click(function(){

    if($('.selectMedia').length < 2 || $(this).hasClass('selectMedia'))
    {
        $(this).toggleClass('selectMedia');
    }
    else
        alert('please unselect one row');
});
```

JsFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZwAHQ/)

Answer (score 0):

Every time you click, you just count the number of items that has that class, and if it is more than two you return without doing something or you display a message that they must deselect one before they can select one more. You just use .lengt or size() to count the items in your div that has that class.

$(".classname).size() or .lengt gives you the number of elements that has that class